# htaccess route all except one file

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, routes, slim

I need to redirect any url to index.php as it is right now except for worker.php file

directories:

```
service/public/index.php
service/public/.htaccess
service/worker.php
```

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Do you mean that the browser can access `worker.php` directly, but you want it to be redirected to index.php?

Comment: no...if url is: website.com/worker.php then it goes to this file, in any other case to index.php

Comment: Well that is dumb because you want to set your webroot to the public directory... otherwise your site will be at domain.com/public/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an additional rewrite condition that says to apply the `index.php` rewrite rule only if `worker.php` is not in the file requested

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !worker\.php$
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```